# How do I fix: "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object"

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've been searching through stackoverflow and other various sites, but I've been unable to resolve this error for about a week now.

I'm trying the get the minimum and maximum values from each country within the dictionary. The key of the dictionary is the region. I'm unsure of where the type error is but, I'd appreciate it if someone could help.

Here's the error:

```
        min_tup, max_tup = get_min_max(D,region,option)
  File "proj08.py", line 107, in get_min_max
    return min[0], max[0]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'min' referenced before assignment
```

Here's the sample input:
Region,option: North America , 2

Here's the documentation explaining the function and .csv
[https://www.cse.msu.edu/~cse231/Online/Projects/Project08/Project08.pdf](https://www.cse.msu.edu/%7Ecse231/Online/Projects/Project08/Project08.pdf)
[https://www.cse.msu.edu/~cse231/Online/Projects/Project08/data_short.csv](https://www.cse.msu.edu/%7Ecse231/Online/Projects/Project08/data_short.csv)

Here's the code:

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter
# do NOT import sys

REGION_LIST = ['East Asia & Pacific',
           'Europe & Central Asia',
           'Latin America & Caribbean',
           'Middle East & North Africa',
           'North America',
           'South Asia',
           'Sub-Saharan Africa']

PROMPT = "\nSpecify a region from this list or 'q' to quit -- \nEast 
Asia & Pacific,Europe & Central Asia,Latin America & Caribbean,Middle 
East & North 
Africa,North America,South Asia,Sub-Saharan Africa: "


def open_file():
# Opens a file
while True:
    try:
        file = input("Input a file: ")
        fp = open(file, "r")
        return fp
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Invalid filename, please try again.")


def read_file(fp):

# Sets read Csv file to a variable
reader = csv.reader(fp)
# Skips the header
next(reader, None)

# Country List
country_list = []
# sets a dictionary
Dict = dict()
for line in reader:
    try:
        skipper = ""
        if skipper in line:
            continue
        else:
            region = line[6]
            country = line[0].strip()
            electricty = float(line[2])
            fertility = float(line[3])
            gdp = float(line[4])
            life_expectancy = float(line[5])

            country_list = [country, electricty, fertility, GDP, 
life_expectancy]

            if region in Dict.keys():
                Dict[region].append(country_list)
            elif region not in Dict.keys():
                Dict[region] = [country_list]
            else:
                continue
                
    except KeyError:
        continue
    except ValueError:
        continue

return Dict


def get_min_max(Dict, region, option):
lis = []
for k, v in Dict.items():
    if region in k[0]:
        if option == 1:
            electricity = v[1]

            tup = tuple(k, electricity)
            lis.append(tup)

            min = sorted(lis, key=itemgetter(1))
            max = sorted(lis, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

        if option == 2:
            fertility = v[2]

            tup = tuple(k, fertility)
            lis.append(tup)

            min = sorted(lis, key=itemgetter(1))
            max = sorted(lis, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

        if option == 3:
            gdp = v[3]

            tup = tuple(k, gdp)
            lis.append(tup)

            min = sorted(lis, key=itemgetter(1))
            max = sorted(lis, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

        if option == 4:
            life_expectancy = v[4]

            tup = tuple(k, life_expectancy)
            lis.append(tup)
            min = sorted(lis, key=itemgetter(1))
            max = sorted(lis, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

return min[0], max[0]


def display_all_countries(D, region):

if region in REGION_LIST:

    if region == 'all':
        print("\nDisplaying {} Region:\n".format(region))
        print("{:32s}{:>20s}{:>20s}{:>17s}{:>18s}".format(
            "Country", "Electricity Access", "Fertility rate", "GDP 
per capita", "Life expectancy"))
        for k, v in D.items():
            if region in v[0]:
                country = v[0]
                electricity = v[1]
                fertility = v[2]
                gdp = v[3]
                life = v[4]
                tup = (country, electricity, fertility, gdp, life)

                sorted(tup, key=itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
                print("{:32s}{:>20.2f}{:>20.2f}{:>17.2f} 
{:>18.2f}".format(
                    tup[0], tup[1], tup[2], tup[3], tup[4]))

if region not in REGION_LIST:
    return None


def get_top10(D):
    pass


def display_options():
    """
    DO NOT CHANGE
    Display menu of options for program
    """
    OPTIONS = """\nMenu
    1: Minimum and Maximum Countries Access to Electricity
    2: Minimum and Maximum Countries Fertility Rate
    3: Minimum and Maximum Countries GDP per Capita
    4: Minimum and Maximum Countries Life Expectancy
    5: List of countries in a region
    6: Top 10 Countries in the world by GDP per Capita\n"""
    print(OPTIONS)


def main():
    file = open_file()
    # while True:
    #     if user == 'East Asia & Pacific' or user == 'Europe & 
    Central Asia' or user == 'Middle East & North Africa' or user == 
   'Latin America & Caribbean' or user == 'North America' or user == 
   'South Asia' or user == 'Sub-Saharan Africa':
#         print("\nRegion: ".format(user))
#         display_options()

#     if user == "Q" or user == "q":
#         break
#     else:
#         user = input(PROMPT)
region = 'North America'
option = '2'
superD = read_file(file)
mina = get_min_max(superD, region, option)

#print(mina)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your return is not properly indented

Comment: On the actual .py, it is, but I had trouble properly indenting the return on here. Does it look okay now? Unless you mean something else, indent it even further.

Comment: Hard to say without a reproducible example. You can add a print statement under `if region not in k[0]:`, if it prints something then there is your problem.

Comment: `if region not in k[0]: return None`. Since you do that, you have to expect `None` out of your function and test for that before you unpack any values.

Comment: The return in the `if region in k[0]:` block means that you'll exit from your function one way or another in the first iteration of `Dict.items()`.

Comment: Okay so now, I'm getting a new error which is: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'min_electricity' referenced before assignment

Comment: Your code has a few issues and by fixing one, you're just moving the goalpost to the next error. Why don't you provide a meaning input example for `Dict`, `option` and `region` and tell us what output you expect?

Comment: @Reti43 I've gone ahead and provided the whole code as well as the csv file and the entire code. In the main post itself. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that you can't use unpacking assignment such as

```
x, y = function()
```

Because the function returned something that can't be unpacked (None, in this case)
This means that your function returned None somehow. We can't say for sure without a reusable example, but I would guess that its because of the first if condition in your function, which can return None.

Although it is allowed, it is generally not a great idea to have multiple different return types in a python function. This is because the caller has to know how to handle different things that the function might do, instead of being able to trust that the function will work and give them a good answer (assuming of course, that they are using correct inputs.)